# we got there just as the shop was ____ (closed/ closing)which is the correct answer?

Tags: past-tense

Fill in the blanks with the correct answer.

> We got there just as the shop was ____ (**closed/ closing)**.

Which is the correct answer?

Comment: I will choose 'closing'. It means when we got there, the shop was closing.

Answer (score 2):

The phrasing here uses "as", meaning something is happening *at the same time* as the speaker got there (see [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as#Conjunction), senses 2 and 3). To indicate an action in progress, we use past continuous - therefore, "was closing" is the correct choice.

"Was closed" would mean the process of closing was already finished when they arrived, even if it only finished the instant before. You would have to use a different phrasing, such as

> We got there *just after* the store was closed.